# About Android Device Manager

Tags: samsung, android-device-manager

My phone is lost and I have locked the phone with the app Android device manager.

Is it locked even if the device is without internet connection?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

No its not. It requires internet connection for ur command to reach to your phone.